# Find unique words

Tags: shell

Suppose there is one file.txt in which below content text is written:

```
ABC/xyz
ABC/xyz/rst
EFG/ghi
```

I need to write a shell script that can extract the first **unique** word before the first `/`.

So as output, I want `ABC` and `EFG` to be written in one file.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first word with `cut` (slash as delimiter), then pipe to `sort` with the `-u` (for "unique") option:

```
$ cut -d '/' -f 1 file.txt | sort -u
ABC
EFG
```

To get the output into a file, just redirect by appending `> filename` to the command. (Or pipe to `tee filename` to see the output *and* get it in a file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
cat file.txt | tr -s "/" ' ' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | sort | uniq > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `tr` here instead of just `awk -F'/'`?

Comment: Just quik, random & working among hundreds of posible solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of cut and sort like so:

```
cut -d '/' -f 1 file.txt | sort -u > newfile.txt
```

The first line grabs any string until a slash `/` and outputs it into newfile.txt.
The second line sorts the text, removing any duplicate strings you might have.

Comment: Surely you meant to say `cut -d '/' -f 1 file.txt | sort | uniq -u > newfile.txt` - Since the OP wants his output in a *file*. Also `sort -u` will allow you to remove the call to `uniq` altogether.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Yes you are right, I appended the unique result on the wrong command, and I just realized that the uniq -u command removes all duplicates, including the first occurrence of the string, which is a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting variation:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $1 |" sort -u" }' file.txt > outfile.txt
```

Not that it matters here, but being able to pipe and redirect within awk can be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way:

```
cut -d"/" -f1 file.txt|uniq > out.txt
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that the `cat` is unnecessary, it does not work if later in the file comes a repetition of a string which has seen earlier, but with different strings in between. For example: `ABC/xxx\nEFG/yyy\nABC/zzz`

Comment: @user1934428- agreed this could been have done without `cat`, but where is the issue with command. It does produce required output with your given input. However, edited my answer to remove cat and make it more efficient.

Comment: That's a different "user" than the one who asked the question ;)

Comment: issue is `uniq` just remove sequenced repeated lines. so without `sort` this will not work. `echo -e "ABC\nEFG"` does produce required output with given input too :)

Comment: @syadav: If you applied your command to the input I suggested, and still got only `ABC\nEFG\n` as a result, you must have a very unusual version of *uniq* on your system. When I do it (my `uniq` has version *(GNU coreutils) 8.25*), I don't receive this output, and this is indeed the behaviour one commonly expects from the `uniq` utility, because it is supposed to remove only *adjecent* duplicates. See [this screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/j5vg7xn57/), which shows your suggestion using *uniq*, and below the one which I consider correct.